# putting contents on an imageview not showing anything

Tags: android, xml

I'm making an app where I have a `cardview` and inside that card view I have an `imageview` on that image view I'm positioning my other components.
Now my problem is as soon as I start using a layout inside image view my design editor goes blank and when removing the layout from image view the image shows again

I tried searching but I didn't get anything related to this specific problem please correct me if I'm going wrong

**below is my XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/feed_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/club1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter">
    <RelativeLayout>
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ellipse"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="John Doe"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checked in to"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_text"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/third_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="W south"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second_text"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fourth_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first_text"
            android:text="beach mumbai"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30 mins ago."
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourth_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/second_text"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: That's not how you use ImageView! remove the </ImageView> tag!

Comment: Instead of putting everything inside ImageView tag, why not setting that image as a background image resource for your CardView or Layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to give hight width to you **`RelativeLayout`** check it

You are adding `view` inside `ImageView`

**FYI**

an
`ImageView` is not  a `ViewGroup` you can not add `view` inside it

**Change your layout like  this**

Try this

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:src="@drawable/abc" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/first_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="John Doe"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/second_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="checked in to"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="9sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/third_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="W south"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fourth_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="beach mumbai"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/second_text"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourth_text"
                        android:text="30 mins ago."
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="9sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="reply to abc............" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="40 likes" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hi @ Nilesh rathod i tried giving height and width to child relative layout still doesnt work

Comment: @Smith just close your `feed_image ImageView` you can not add view inside imageview tag just try my ans

Comment: @Smith can u share your expected output

Comment: sure just hold on a moment

Comment: it works and how can i add the other component like favourite button and other textviews

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved the day

Comment: @Smith happy to help u

Comment: can i ask you for one more help if you would like

Comment: @Smith yes sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169575/discussion-between-smith-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

Wrong `ImageView` close tag as well `RelativeLayout` `height` & `width` are missing. Please check code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/feed_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/club1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"></ImageView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ellipse"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="John Doe"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checked in to"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_text"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/third_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="W south"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second_text"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fourth_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first_text"
            android:text="beach mumbai"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30 mins ago."
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourth_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/second_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're treating `ImageView` like it was a `ViewGroup`, which it isn't. You can only nest views inside a `ViewGroup`. The simplest solution to your question would be to take everything you've put inside `ImageView` and put it inside your parent `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/feed_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/club1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ellipse"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="John Doe"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="checked in to"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_text"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/third_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="W south"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second_text"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fourth_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first_text"
            android:text="beach mumbai"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30 mins ago."
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourth_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/second_text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```